# Unexpected trailing slash behaviour with Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm seeing unexpected behaviour (at least as per me) with trailing slashes on Firebase Hosting. I expect Firebase to serve URLs with a trailing slash (except for actual files present in the hosting directory). For this I set `trailingSlash` to `true` in firebase.json.

This resulted in:

```
example.com                     redirect to     example.com/index.html/
example.com/js/script.js        redirect to     example.com/js/script.js/
example.com/images/image.png    redirect to     example.com/images/image.png/
```

The expected behaviour would be:

```
example.com                     redirect to example.com/
example.com/js/script.js        served as it is without any redirect
example.com/images/image.png    served as it is without any redirect
```

The addition of trailing slash to actual file URLs makes the browser/server think `script.js` is a directory instead of file and results in a 404. The addition of index.html to the root simply isn't elegant.

Expecting `cleanUrls` to do the trick I set `cleanUrls` to `true` along with `trailingSlash` and immediately the site goes into an endless redirect loop and fails to load. How can I stop Firebase from adding "index.html" at the root and the trailing slash for the actual js or image assets?

Edit:

As requested by Frank here's the firebase.json I'm using:

```
{
    "firebase"          : "example",
    "public"            : "public",
    "cleanUrls"         : false,
    "trailingSlash"     : true,
    "ignore"            : [ "firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**" ],
    "rewrites": [{

        "source"        : "**",
        "destination"   : "/index.html"

    }],
    "headers": [{

        "source"    : "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
        "headers"   : [{

            "key"   : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "value" : "*"
        }]

    }, {

        "source"    : "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
        "headers"   : [{
            "key"   : "Cache-Control",
            "value" : "max-age=600"
        }]

    }, {

        "source"    : "**/*.@(html|js)",
        "headers"   : [{
            "key"   : "Cache-Control",
            "value" : "max-age=300"
        }]

    }]
}
```

P.S.: I have tried setting both `trailingSlash` and `cleanUrls` to `true` and also tried setting these `true/false` individually.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Please see the updated question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I hope you had the chance to look at the edit as requested by you?

Answer (score 3):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#trailingslash

> When true, it will redirect URLs to add a trailing slash. When false
>   it will redirect URLs to remove a trailing slash. When unspecified,
>   trailing slashes are used only for directory index files (e.g.
>   about/index.html).

Just do not add that option and it will *only* affect urls

Answer (score 0):

As for your question, If you want to invoke the command "rewrites", Server can execute "rewirtes" command when he cannot find any index.html in your root directory.

The solution one:
you just put index.html in your root directory under your "public" folder. I switch to your public folder and deploy your server.

The solution two:
 you put index.html under some folder which you can named whatever. Then use JSON format: `"rewrites": [{ "source" : "**", "destination" : "/folderName/index.html" }],` but you cannot put any index.html under your root folder.

The solution three:
you create root folder, put your JS/CSS/IMG/  folders  and index.html under the root folder. Then you deploy server JSON file like this.

```
{
"firebase": "you app name",
"public": ".",
"ignore": [
"firebase.json",
"**/.*",
"**/node_modules/**"
],
```

Comment: I followed the solutions you outlined without luck. I was probably not clear with my description of the issue. The problem is with `trailingSlash` when set to `true` results in `example.com` redirect to `example.com/index.html/`, `example.com/js/script.js` redirect to `example.com/js/script.js/` and `example.com/css/style.css` redirect to `example.com/css/style.css/`. Notice the trailing slash at the end of file (script.js and style.css) URLs. The trailing slash "should not" be added to file URLs. Addition of trailing slash to file URLs results in those URLs... (see next comment)

Comment: (continued)...  rewritten to `index.html`. Then we have another issue of `example.com` redirect to `example.com/index.html/` which is not elegant. The second issue again is caused by setting `trailingSlash` to `true` and is not related to rewite rules.

I have setup a demo Firebase to recreate the issue. Please follow the following links `https://scorching-torch-3741.firebaseapp.com/css/style.css`, `https://scorching-torch-3741.firebaseapp.com/js/script.js` and `https://scorching-torch-3741.firebaseapp.com/`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is too late for Vinny, but I just ran into this same issue. Adding `<base href='/'>`to my html files prevented the extra unexpected trailing slash behavior for me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
"hosting": {
  "public": "...",
  "ignore": [...],
  "trailingSlash": false
}
```

Simply add **trailingSlash** property and set it to **false** will remove the trailing slash when firebase redirects. Check out their details [documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#control_trailing_slashes)